# Non-ECR category for an Indian Passport, without birth certificate, class 10 cert. and tax returns

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, paperwork, india

I am applying for a new Indian Passport for my dad. Since he is above 50, the website is taking Non-[Emigration Check Required (ECR)](https://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr) category by default.

The problem is my dad does not have the following documents:

1. No birth certificate
2. Although he has passed class 10, we do not have a class 10
   certificate. The school was in our village and is probably closed
   now.
3. He has a PAN card and it has the correct birthdate, but he has been
   retired (business) from quite sometime now. We do not have any
   Income tax return file or anything.

What else can be used to prove Non-ECR category?

Comment: what did you finally use for the non-ECR proof ? I am in the same pickle, my mom des not have birth certificate or school leaving certificate. Please let me know.

Comment: From the question and the answer given, a PAN card. But as this is not an answer to the question it has to be deleted. (I can convert it into a comment and hope you get more information.)

Comment: An explanation what **ECR** is would be nice.

Comment: @MarkJohnson https://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr

Comment: @Sonali If I remember correctly only the Aadhar card did the trick. But give me some time I will ask them and get back. Commenting now to inform that I am inquiring and will get back.

Comment: Thank you for this question. I am facing the exact same problem. I do not have birth/ educational proof for my mom. However, have PAN and Aadhar. By default she falls under non ECR due to her age. Will the application be accepted basis PAN and Aadhar only?

Comment: For my parents it was accepted. But I must mention that we approached an agent for this, and he took care of most the formalities. I was not even in the same city at that moment so I am not sure which options he chose for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PAN card is an identity document. Its valid even if you did not file income tax or used for sometime. It can be used to prove the date of birth.

See: https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/PressRelease_PassportRule.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response Anish.. What I am unsure is, it says it can be used as proof of DOB, but I dont see anywhere written that it will work for proving non-ECR status.. That is making me doubt whether it will work or not..

Comment: PAN Card has date of birth, right? So, its a verified information. You can use that for proving age and thereby granting non-ECR.